# Why buttons are outside of JQM popup's footer

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup, footer

Using Jquery-mobile, the following (abbreviated here) footer

```
<div data-role="footer">
    <a href="#table" data-role="button" data-icon="plus"
    data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">Open</a>
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="delete"
    data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
</div>
```

that exist in a popup, when popped-up, its buttons
are displayed outside the popup-frame, aligned under it.

Why? What am I doing wrong?

The full example is in http://jsfiddle.net/yotam/d0aqmx6m/

Answer (score 1):

I'm beginning to wonder if button footers are not supported in popups.  Or at least, not fully supported.  From the docs, you need to throw a "ui-title" in there too - it's what will give the footer height (The docs show a span after the button definitions).

I've done that here:

```
<div data-role="footer">
  <a href="#table" class="ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-plus">Open</a>
  <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-delete">Close</a>
   <span class="ui-title"></span>
</div>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/had4or71/

Of course, it only partially solves your problem, as though they are now in the footer, they don't yet look good.  I tried with a navbar in the footer with similarly disappointing results (the navbar was well positioned top, bottom, and left, but ran over the right border pretty badly.

Finally, I did this version real quick as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/ph0e54ee/2/

Which shows pushing the close button into the header like the demos site does, and just presenting your open button inline as a standard button - alas, it's a compromise, and not what you asked for.

On further investigation, it would appear the "ui-btn-left" and "ui-btn-right" classes are not supported in the footer, see:

- [gh:6331](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6331)
- [gh:6872](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6872)
- [gh:6137 (comment)](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6137#issuecomment-20569793)

Again, I messed about with the CSS a bit, and managed to get something sort of nice, at least on my test browser of chrome.  I suspect your mileage will vary greatly outside of chrome.: http://jsfiddle.net/9crnjakr/